# Write a program Java that creates three new threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Write a program Java that creates three new threads (besides the already existing main thread)
and synchronizes them in such a way that each thread displays it's thread id in turn for 5 iterations.
The output of the program should look like this:

Thread 1 - iteration no. 1

Thread 2 - iteration no. 1

Thread 3 - iteration no. 1

Thread 1 - iteration no. 2

Thread 2 - iteration no. 2

Thread 3 - iteration no. 2

Thread 1 - iteration no. 3

Thread 2 - iteration no. 3

Thread 3 - iteration no. 3

Thread 1 - iteration no. 4

Thread 2 - iteration no. 4

Thread 3 - iteration no. 4

Thread 1 - iteration no. 5

Thread 2 - iteration no. 5

Thread 3 - iteration no. 5

**Code:**

```
package ZTest;
public class PrintSequenceRunnable2 implements Runnable{

    public int PRINT_NUMBERS_UPTO=15;
    static int  number=1;
    int remainder;
    static Object lock=new Object();

    PrintSequenceRunnable2(int remainder)
    {
        this.remainder=remainder;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (number < PRINT_NUMBERS_UPTO-1) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (number % 3 != remainder) { 
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "- iteration no. " + number);
                number++;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintSequenceRunnable2 runnable1=new PrintSequenceRunnable2(1);
        PrintSequenceRunnable2 runnable2=new PrintSequenceRunnable2(2);
        PrintSequenceRunnable2 runnable3=new PrintSequenceRunnable2(0);

            Thread t1=new Thread(runnable1,"Thread1");
            Thread t2=new Thread(runnable2,"Thread2");
            Thread t3=new Thread(runnable3,"Thread3");

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();   
        }
    }
```

**My output:**

```
Thread1- iteration no. 1
Thread2- iteration no. 2
Thread3- iteration no. 3
Thread1- iteration no. 4
Thread2- iteration no. 5
Thread3- iteration no. 6
Thread1- iteration no. 7
Thread2- iteration no. 8
Thread3- iteration no. 9
Thread1- iteration no. 10
Thread2- iteration no. 11
Thread3- iteration no. 12
Thread1- iteration no. 13
Thread2- iteration no. 14
Thread3- iteration no. 15
```

**Expected output:**

```
Thread 1 - iteration no. 1

Thread 2 - iteration no. 1

Thread 3 - iteration no. 1

Thread 1 - iteration no. 2

Thread 2 - iteration no. 2

Thread 3 - iteration no. 2

Thread 1 - iteration no. 3

Thread 2 - iteration no. 3

Thread 3 - iteration no. 3

Thread 1 - iteration no. 4

Thread 2 - iteration no. 4

Thread 3 - iteration no. 4

Thread 1 - iteration no. 5

Thread 2 - iteration no. 5

Thread 3 - iteration no. 5
```

Comment: I don't know what book introduced this horrible exercise, but teachers keep assigning variations on it. It teaches something about _how_ to synchronize the action of different threads, but it gives an utterly wrong idea of _when_ to synchronize. Making threads take turns like that completely defeats the purpose of having threads, which is to let different activities in the program happen _concurrently_ with each other. A multi-threaded program always needs some synchronization, but less is better. The more you couple the threads to each other, the less benefit there is from having threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow ^ yes, this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one crude way to do this. The whole idea is that one thread unlocks the execution of another thread. You can use cyclic barrier to do the same.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class SyncThreeThreads implements Runnable {

    private final Semaphore previous;

    private final Semaphore next;

    public SyncThreeThreads(Semaphore previous, Semaphore next) {
        this.previous = previous;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            waitForPreviousLock();

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Iteration no. "+ (i+1));

            releaseForNext();
        }
    }

    private void releaseForNext() {
        next.release();
    }

    private void waitForPreviousLock() {
        try {
            previous.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static public void main(String argv[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Semaphore lock1 = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore lock2 = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore lock3 = new Semaphore(1);

        lock1.acquire();
        lock2.acquire();
        lock3.acquire();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new SyncThreeThreads(lock3, lock1),"Thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new SyncThreeThreads(lock1, lock2),"Thread 2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new SyncThreeThreads(lock2, lock3),"Thread 3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        lock3.release();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3026703 : Welcome. Try experimenting with CyclicBarrier too for fun.

Answer (score 1):

I find this a weird question because you're basically implementing threads while also completely nullifying the use out of them.

But here's my suggestion:

Currently you're printing the following

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "- iteration no. " + number);
```

The easiest way to make the numbers follow the scheme you want is by dividing the counter by the number of threads and calling math.floor on the result. Like this:

```
int iteration = Math.floor(number / 3.0) + 1; //3.0 is the amount of threads
```

This would hold the result you're asking for. Keep in mind that, since your counter starts on 1, you may have to subtract 1 from `number` to make it align properly.

Comment: Thread1- iteration no. 1
Thread2- iteration no. 1
Thread3- iteration no. 2
Thread1- iteration no. 2
Thread2- iteration no. 2
Thread3- iteration no. 3
Thread1- iteration no. 3
Thread2- iteration no. 3
Thread3- iteration no. 4
Thread1- iteration no. 4
Thread2- iteration no. 4
Thread3- iteration no. 5
Thread1- iteration no. 5
Thread2- iteration no. 5
Thread3- iteration no. 6

Comment: Answer is not appropriate because for first thread its not running 3 times

Comment: @user3026703 that's why I mentioned the fact that you may have to offset number by one. Meaning it becomes `Math.floor((number - 1) / 3.0) + 1;`

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to have any sort of counter start on 1, that's why I didn't keep that in mind in my example. It's best to make counters start at 0, that's basically the norm.